# How to define a common data section for diffrent arm assembly files?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have just started learning arm assembly using a Arm Cortex M4 based microcontroller STM32F446RE. After creating some successful project, i created a new project in following manner

```
main.s
init.s
delay.s
startup_stm32f446xx.s
LinkerScript.ld
Makefile

compiler : arm-none-eabi-gcc
system   : linux mint
```

I noticed that data section of `main.s, init.s and delay.s` had some common peripheral base addresses

so i created a new file `phr_adrs.s` defined all the addresses in this file, removed the data section of `main.s init.s and delay.s` and accessed those addresses in these files.

my `main.s`, `delay.s` and `init.s`  have following similar lines of code :

```
...
LDR  R3, =AHB1ENR # AHB1ENR is defined into **phr_adrs.s**
...

...
LDR  R4, =GPIOA # GPIOA is defined into **phr_adrs.s**
...

...
LDR  R5, =SYSTICK # SYSTICK is defined into **`phr_adrs.s`**
...

etc.
```

when i build the project, got some linking errors saying : `undefined reference to 'label'`

so i updated the phr_adrs.s file by defining every label global

now `phr_adrs.s` looks like this :

```
.global AHB1ENR
.global APB2ENR
.global SYSCFG
.global GPIOA
.global GPIOC
.global ISER1
.global IPR10
.global EXTI

.data
    .equ AHB1ENR, 0x40023830
    .equ APB2ENR, 0x40023844
    .equ SYSCFG,  0x40013800
    .equ GPIOA,   0x40020000
    .equ GPIOC,   0x40020800
    .equ ISER1,   0xE000E104
    .equ IPR10,   0xE000E428
    .equ EXTI,    0x40013C00
```

my question is that "**is their a better way to do this? like what if i need to define 100s of peripheral base address do i need to define those labels global as well.**"

alternatively

**How to define base addresses of all the peripheral in one file (just like a header file in C) and
access those addresses into different files?**

I tried searching the internet and stack**overflow** but didn't get any answer.

Comment: You are for some unknown reason using a super low level language (assembly) but asking how to get a feature of a higher level language (C).  The real question is why are you using assembly in the first place?  Assembly should only be used either for critical sections where the performance of an optimizing C compiler isn't good enough (which is almost never) or to use special processor features that can't be expressed in C (which should only ever be a handful of lines at most).

Comment: ... so what you are asking for can be answered in terms of clever linker scripts or using the C pre-processor with assembly, but given that you have to use at least a bit of a higher language, why not just be sensible and do the whole thing in a higher level language?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Tom for telling me that this is a high level feature. Well the reason is that I'm learning arm assembly because i like low level programming and electronics. And this is my first time with all this stuff. I'm just a high school pass out starting my journey into world of embedded system. I just observed it and wanted to make my code efficient and save some time.

Comment: @TomV Try matrix transpose with neon in C intrinsics. You will then renounce that **almost never**

Comment: You can include files instead of linking them

Comment: `.equ` isn't part of any section, it's an assemble-time constant.  It's more like `#define` in C.  Or `static const int foo = 123;` - note the `static` which lets the compiler optimize it out and not make it part of the object file.  Again, you need that in a `.h` file that each `.c` includes with `#include`.  The asm equivalent is `.include "constants.S"`.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: that is something that is almost never done!

Comment: @TomV Sure, it gets never done while writing the 100th hello world.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: no, it gets done once and put in a library, and then everyone who wants to invert a matrix just calls the library. :-)

Comment: @TomV Which library? If you mean OpenCV, I hope you are fine with functions that take 4~5 times  as long as necessary.